# Xamarin Forms button event not firing on Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app, in one of my pages I have two buttons, on Android when you tap the button it does not fire the event, it just highlights the button, if you tap a second time then it fires the event, on iOS it runs flawlessly. Below is some Code extracts, sorry if my code has bad practices, I am a noob, so please do correct me, best way to learn:

//Initialize Page

```
public GameDetailsNew(Game myEvent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyEvent.Text = myEvent.EventName;
        MyTimeHeader.Text = myEvent.TimeOfEvent;
        myEventID = myEvent.EventID;
        Task.Run(() => { GetAttendingEvent(myEvent.EventID); });
    }
```

//GetAttendingEvent

```
private void GetAttendingEvent(int eventID)
    {
        var registerLable = "";
        var attendinIsVisible = false;
        var notAttendingIsVisible = false;
        try
        {
            HelperFiles.APICaller ac = new HelperFiles.APICaller();
            var x = (string)ac.CallCOFMOBILEBool("GetIsAttending?eventID=" + eventID);
            if (x == "Attending")
            {
                registerLable = "You are currently Attending this Event";
                attendinIsVisible = false;
                notAttendingIsVisible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                registerLable = "You are currently NOT Attending this Event";
                attendinIsVisible = true;
                notAttendingIsVisible = false;
            }
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    RegisterLable.Text = registerLable;
                    AttendingButton.IsVisible = attendinIsVisible;
                    NotAttendingButton.IsVisible = notAttendingIsVisible;
                });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MyAlerts("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
    }
```

//My To Button Event Handlers

```
//Sets User as attending event
    void AttendingClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HelperFiles.APICaller ac = new HelperFiles.APICaller();
            var x = (string)ac.CallCOFMOBILEBool("GetCreateAttending?eventID=" + myEventID);
            if (x == "1")
            {
                RegisterLable.Text = "You are currently Attending this Event";
                AttendingButton.IsVisible = false;
                NotAttendingButton.IsVisible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                RegisterLable.Text = "You are currently NOT Attending this Event";
                AttendingButton.IsVisible = true;
                NotAttendingButton.IsVisible = false;
            }
            GetDeployingEvent(myEventID);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MyAlerts("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
        }

    }

    //Sets User as Not attending event
    void NotAttendingClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HelperFiles.APICaller ac = new HelperFiles.APICaller();
            var x = (string)ac.CallCOFMOBILEBool("GetCreateNotAttending?eventID=" + myEventID);
            if (x != "1")
            {
                RegisterLable.Text = "You are currently Attending this Event";
                AttendingButton.IsVisible = false;
                NotAttendingButton.IsVisible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                RegisterLable.Text = "You are currently NOT Attending this Event";
                AttendingButton.IsVisible = true;
                NotAttendingButton.IsVisible = false;
            }
            GetDeployingEvent(myEventID);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MyAlerts("Error", ex.Message, "OK");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to update on this, I managed to resolve the issue. about 8 months ago I started my project in Xamarin Studio, fast forward a few months, Xamarin Studios changed to Visual Studio. No matter what i done i could not get rid of this bug, I then started a brand new app and pasted all my code in to the new app. This has resolved the bug.